# Express session property not setting in schema

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, express-session

I'm trying to use an `express-session` property to set a value in a Mongoose document, however whenever I do it returns a "Path `ownerId` is required".

I've tried logging the variable to the console, both before and after the mongoose Model is created.

```
router.post('/create', (req, res) => {
  console.group();
  var propertyId = randomString(11);

  var ownerId = req.session.userId;

  console.log("ownerId value: " + ownerId);

  var newProperty = new Property({
    _id: propertyId,
    owner: ownerId,
    address: req.body.address,
    landline: req.body.landline
  });

  console.log("ownerId value: " + ownerId);

  Property.create(newProperty, (err, property) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.send(property);
    }
  });
  console.groupEnd();
});
```

I expected both `console.log`'s to output the ID, which they did, but I also expected the `newUser` object to contain the ID, but since I got a validator error on the `Property.save` function, I know that it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Path ownerId is required` message

This mean in your table schema (`Property` scheme) has defined a filed called - `ownerId`, but when you create a new `Property`, input data does not include `ownerId` field.

I see your input data includes `owner: ownerId,`, just check again your table schema.